# Fatal Error : call to undefined function , PHP

Tags: php

I am working with php, and trying to call a function within a block of code, but I do not know why it causing the error that `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function GetUserIDFromUsername()`, while it is defined later then.

**The PHP Code**

```js
 if(isset($_GET["updateRow"])){
   
             $_fbURL  = $_GET["ajaxified"];
             
             if(!empty($_fbURL)){
                    $url = $_fbURL;
                    $urlParts = explode("facebook.com/", $url);
                    $username = GetUserIDFromUsername($urlParts[1]);



                function GetUserIDFromUsername($username) {
                    // For some reason, changing the user agent does expose the user's UID
                    $options  = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'some_obscure_browser'));
                    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
                    $fbsite = file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/' . $username, false, $context);

                    // ID is exposed in some piece of JS code, so we'll just extract it
                    $fbIDPattern = '/\"entity_id\":\"(\d+)\"/';
                    if (!preg_match($fbIDPattern, $fbsite, $matches)) {
                        throw new Exception('Unofficial API is broken or user not found');
                    }
                    return $matches[1];
                }

                echo "My Id is : "." ".$username;

             } 
               
               
                    
           
           }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are parsing exact data from the **URL**? Be sure about the response.

Comment: when   I try the same code just removing the isset method, then it returns the required data, you can try that on a simple php, providing your facebook url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your method GetUserIDFromUsername($params) before calling it.
You can move the method to the top of the caller.